# Inconsistent number of beats per measure

Tags: time-signatures, baroque-period

This perhaps just betrays my ignorance, but I don't understand why in the attached piece, in 3/4 time, certain bars, such as 10 and 12, have 6 instead of 3 quarter notes, with no change in the time signature.

What hints are there for the performer to know such a change occurs, and why is the notation as such? Is this device characteristic only of 17/18th century music?

Most importantly, how not to get confused when singing this?[image]

Comment: I'll let others elaborate, but this is about [hemiola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola)

Comment: Do you have the edition information? other than pointing out the score has an implied switch to 6/4, and it does that to notate three groups of 2 beats, which is the hemiola, without the need to use ties over the bar line in 3/4, I wonder how the historic 18th century scores looked. My modern scores of Baroque music sometimes explicitly notate meter changes. I wonder if your edition is preserving how the meter change was original implied, not written out, of it was a modern editor's choice.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I looked it up earlier; the 1884 Chrysander score, at least, has just like this but with vertical strike marks through the middle half note

Comment: @AndyBonner - if indeed it is a hemiola, that doesn't explain why there are 'too many notes' in those bars. Surely the bar lines ought to be there, and the 2nd minims replaced by tied crotchets?

Comment: Sadly I don't have any addition information about this particular score. But I suspect it was produced in Musescore by our local conductor, so it could well be that it is simply a mistake on his part. Else, from what I read about the definition of the hemiola, it doesn't quite seem to match, let alone be of any help to the person deciphering the music

Comment: I wouldn't think it's a mistake. Whoever notated it, took some extra steps to produce these double-measures. That's intentional.

Comment: yup that makes sense. Btw I meant "edition" above, not "addition" :)

Comment: This page does an excellent job of explaining the concept: https://www.helenhooker.co.uk/blog/2022/7/4/how-do-you-hemiola By the way, the manuscript of Serse is available on IMSLP. I haven’t had time yet to hunt down this number in act iii, but I’m willing to bet big money it’s notated this way there. I can go looking for other examples of this “fused bar” approach and write up an answer later; I feel like I’ve run into it mostly in earlier music than Handel, maybe French?

Comment: @AndyBonner - FWIW, the urtext (I was unable to find a manuscript in IMSLP of any part of *Serse* but the overture), accessible [here](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/c/c9/IMSLP780566-PMLP24130-00._HANDEL_-_XERXES,_HWV_40_(STEGLICH)_-_Conductor's_Score.PDF), **uses 3/4 time throughout and does not fuse any measures together**.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Yeah my bad, the manuscript I saw at a quick glance was Overture only

Comment: @Dekkadeci the supposed urtext isn't really.  Or adopts the common "urtext" practice of modernizing notation without comment (except perhaps in the editorial notes).

Comment: "from what I read about the definition of the hemiola, it doesn't quite seem to match": what doesn't match?

Comment: @AndyBonner the name for that vertical strike mark is "bar line" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What hints are there for the performer to know such a change occurs

Count the beats in the measure!

> and why is the notation as such?

The answer to this question probably lies in the original sources for the opera.  Unfortunately, none of these seem to be available online.  In addition to manuscript scores, one can also look at manuscript performing parts.  A comprehensive list of available sources may be found at [RISM](https://opac.rism.info/metaopac/refineSearch.do?id=manuskriptstatement_facet&methodToCall=filterSearch&subval=Manuscriptcopy).

Another possible source of this information is the editorial notes to any modern scholarly edition.  You should be able to find these by visiting any research music library.  You may also be able to find a copy in a sheet music store, though sheet music stores are increasingly difficult to find these days.

> Is this device characteristic only of 17/18th century music?

Not only, but primarily.  You'll find it in the Renaissance, though it was largely less formulaic then, and you can certainly find it in the nineteenth century, though it is typically found in music that evokes the older classical and baroque styles.

While I could not find manuscript sources online, nor (unsurprisingly) the editorial notes accompanying the modern editions, I did find a scan of the contemporaneous engraved score.  This has an odd quirk that I haven't seen before.  There aren't any bars that are twice as long as the others; equivalently, there are no missing bar lines.  Neither are the measures in question notated with ties as shown in other answers.  Instead, the half note is *centered on the bar line*:

[image: detail of the Walsh edition of Xerxes showing an excerpt from the movement in question]

This is very odd by modern standards, but it is not so odd if you consider that ties across the barline were also avoided for dotted rhythms by writing the dot for a note that starts on the last beat of one measure on the downbeat of the following measure:

[image: detail showing augmentation dot on downbeat]

The scan can be found [on Google Books](https://books.google.at/books?id=KbRIcDiJPQYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Xerxes+handel&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj39amhjoiEAxUM97sIHav1AzoQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false) (the movement in question is on page 97).

> Most importantly, how not to get confused when singing this?

At first, the easiest way, if the tempo is moderate to slow as it is here, is to count as it is barred here: instead of 1-2-3, 1-2-3 count 1-and-2-and-3-and -- but be sure that the quarter note beat remains constant.  Once you're more familiar with the style, where this rhythmic shift happens at almost every cadence in triple meter, you will start doing it automatically.

Comment: No wonder the urtext publishers revolted and used ties instead.

Comment: @Dekkadeci indeed.  We do have to remember to take "urtext" with a grain of salt.  Urtext editions of Bach's keyboard works, for example, wouldn't be particularly saleable if they were published using the original soprano clef for the upper staff.

Answer (score 8):

If it makes you happier, you could edit those bars to insert the missing bar lines, then convert the second minim/half note to two tied crotchets/quarter notes, e.g.
[image]

As Andy Bonner notes in a comment, it's hemiola.  Every now and then the music changes to have the same beat pattern, but at half the speed (double the duration of each note).  For the least subtle example of hemiola ever, listen to America from West Side Story.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be dismayed by the notation; they just need an explanation of hemiola

Comment: That is of course a trivial edit to make but what *would* make me happier is to understand to what purpose this change of notation is used in the first place, assuming that it isn't a trivial mistake (see previous comment)

Comment: @AndyBonner: The wikipedia page you linked to above describes hemiola as "three beats of equal value in the time normally occupied by two beats" - eg "♩♩♩" in the time of "♩. ♩.", but this seems to be "one beat in the time of two" ("♩" in the time of "♪♪"). Can the term refer to both, then?

Comment: @psmears This is the same as the Wikipedia example with the note values doubled (three half-notes in the space of two dotted half-notes). It's actually more typical and would be a better example for Wikipedia.

Comment: @PiedPiper: I guess my confusion is that there aren't any dotted-half-note rhythms around the bars in question to contrast with; is the idea that the contrast is with pairs of bars from the surrounding music? (Otherwise you could equally claim that the first line of the piece is all hemiolas because it has "♩♩♩" played in the time of "♩. ♩."...)

Comment: @psmears The meter is 3/4 (and is supported by the music, until the hemiolas come), so there **is** a 3-quarter note length pulse established.

Comment: @user1079505: OK - that's what I was trying to get at with "pairs of bars from the surrounding music" - so the contrast is with the timing of the whole bars, rather than any rhythm played within them, then. Thanks!

Comment: @psmears since hemiola means "one and a half," it may be more accurate to think of it as three groups of 2/4 in the space that is normally occupied by two groups of 3/4.  This makes more sense when the rhythm is primarily in quarters and eighths rather than in halves and quarters as it is here, but in any event it's defined by the meter, not the rhythm.

Comment: @phoog: Thanks that's helpful. The wikipedia page is definitely not as clear as it could be!

Answer (score 2):

There is an urtext version available here:
https://imslp.org/wiki/Serse,_HWV_40_(Handel,_George_Frideric)

The part in question is on page 161 of the score:
[image]

...and it uses 3/4 meter with ties over the bar line.

The rhythmic effect of that passage is called *hemiola* which is a rhythm based on the ratio of `3:2`. In this particular case it is a switch from metrical grouping by 3, which is the `3/4` meter, to grouping by 2, which is the three two-beat durations. You can think of it like a type of syncopation, because of the way the sense of strong beats shifts around. In `3/4` the third beat of measure is normally weak, but with the hemiola rhythm that third beat tied to the next one beat gets a kind of emphasis that contrast to the prevailing `3/4` meter.

Switching meter from `3/4` to an implied `6/4` is just a way to avoid notating ties over the bar lines. For good or bad that choice was made by the editor of the specific edition you have.

Comment: The editor's choice is actually closer to the Walsh edition than the supposed urtext edition, whose editor has chosen to add ties where it seems that none exist in the source.

Comment: @phoog is that Walsh edition available at IMSLP?

Comment: I don't think so.  I found it on Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a hemiola. A brief drop into 'half time', normally in a triple meter.  They occur all through the history of notated music, and are sometimes written with apparent disregard for the rules of notation, as in your example.

How not to get confused?  Just believe the notation.  Now you know it ISN'T a mistake, it won't be confusing!

Answer (score -2):

Putting my neck on the line here: it may not be a hemiola, but a poor writing, or printing, where  bar lines have been missed, and ties not applied. Any piece in 3/4 time *should* have three crotchets in each bar (excluding anacruces!), and it's patently obvious that this piece has ended u with 6 instead in some bars.

The fact that two minims won't fit into a bar in 3/4 time is fundamental, so to keep the timing of the tune, there would need to be a bar line after 3 beats, and the second minim in that bar tied across in the form of one crotchet tied to the first crotchet in the next bar. It will all sound the same, count the same, read and play the same - and be technically correct.

I've yet to find a hemiola which isn't contained within a single bar, which abides by the 'rule' of correct number of beats in each bar. And while knowing what a hemiola is, there's no need to understand it for this example.

First port of call must be your conductor. Second, probably, re-write it so there's a bar line and tied crotchets.

And the usual unexplained dvs will follow...

Comment: They **are** hemiolas. Some editor has tried to make them even more obvious than they would be already.

Comment: See Schumann example from the wikipedia page for a two-bar hemiola example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola

Comment: @user1079505 - I agree totally that there is at least one hemiola there, but there's also the requisite number of bar lines - which is my point. To make it *really* obvious, there should be a time signature change!

Comment: @Tim While adding time signatures (or barlines and tied notes) would indeed be strictly correct, your conductor may have thought that the intention was already very clear, and that adding time signatures at the start of 4 consecutive bars would have made it harder, not easier to read.

Comment: It's a common enough way of making these hemiolas visible, so it's not a violation of the rules, but a special exception. Think of it as a two-bar meter change without bothering to spell out the time signature. (Except it's more like "both meters are true simultaneously," thus the fun cognitive dissonance.)

Comment: @AndyBonner - apart from the example  in the question, I've not seen another where there's a missing bar line. And I've searched and searched. All others are contained within single bars.

Comment: @PiedPiper I suspect that Handel wrote half notes in his working score and that he either drew a bar line through the half note (as printed in the first edition) or left the barline out.  His working scores were typically not barred very strictly, but fair copies and printed editions were, so copyists and editors have been struggling ever since to figure out the best way to deal with this.

Comment: @AndyBonner, Tim: I've seen more than a few modern editions use bars of double length for hemiola, but most of them have been from the early 17th century where the source had no bar lines at all. I did sing a piece recently by Maurizio Cazzati, so later 17th century (published in 1682, to be precise), where the modern edition used this approach, but I haven't seen the source